# Hypersurfaces of a hemisphere

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, spherical-geometry, compact-manifolds

Let $S_+^{n+1}$ be the open hemisphere of the standard euclidean sphere centered at the north pole and let $M^n$ be a compact, connected and oriented hypersurface of $S_+^{n+1}$. Is it true that if $M$ has nowhere zero Gauss-Kronecker curvature then all its principal curvatures have the same sign?

I heard this follows from the fact that $M$ has an elliptic point, but I don't know why this is true nor it implies my question.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check this paper: RIGIDITY AND CONVEXITY OF HYPERSURFACES
IN SPHERES, by M. P. DO CARMO & F. W. WARNER. Journal of Differential Geometry - 4(1970) 133-144.
Best
Ronaldo Freire